# Column o shell script

Tags: bash, shell, dns

I create a shell script to get DNS values from domain, I have the queries below:

`A=$(dig CNAME +noadditional +noquestion +nocomments +nocmd +nostats +norec google.com. @a.gtld-servers.net | grep -v SOA | sort -dbf)`

`B=$(dig A +noquestion +nocomments +nocmd +nostats +norec google.com. @a.gtld-servers.net | grep A | awk '{print $5}')`

I need to make a column to show results side-by-side, example:

OUTPUT A | OUTPUT B

Is there a way to make this?

I tried column -t but don't show formatted correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
paste -d '-' <(echo "$A") <(echo "$B")
```

#### Example

```
$ cat file1
hello bye
haha buu
$ cat file2
aaa
ooo
$ a=$(cat file1)
$ b=$(cat file2)
$ paste -d '-' <(echo "$a") <(echo "$b")
hello bye-aaa
haha buu-ooo
```

Comment: Very useful. Thank you fedorqui